# can't find file after calling mkfile from cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, perl, bash, cocoa

i've built a cocoa app which uses NSTask in order to call a perl script (myScript.pl) I wrote. the script itself executes another script (copy.command).

the copy.command script calles "mkfile", copy the file that was created (file is called 'test1') to a given location. at the end of the run i don't delete 'test1' (for various reasons).

iv'e used these scripts countless times and it always worked. before i made my app (meaning when i used the terminal) - there were always two files at the end, both with the same name in different location.

both scripts were added to my project. like i said i use NSTask.

i know both scripts are being executed because i can still find 'test1' file after the script is done. but, and this is my problem, i can only find one 'test1' file after script has finished - the one that were copied to another folder. but the 'test1' file that was created by 'mkfile' is no where to be found.

my questions:

1. is the file gone? i know it is created cause i can find it's copy in the other folder. but i want to see the original as well.
2. maybe i should make the file in a folder outside the .app folder? if u think that is the solution plz tell me how to pass to 'mkfile' an absolute path.
3. I've thought about capturing the output to see if something is going wrong but i'm not sure how to do that
4. a new solution came to me: maybe I should try and changeDir to a "system folder" of some sort in the bash script, call mkfile, copy, compare, and changeDir back. what say u?

i use macbook air, osx 10.9.2, xcode 5.1

thanks
zook2005

this is the copy command

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -r "test1" ]]
then
mkfile -n 1g test1
fi

cp -f test1 /Volumes/$1/test1 &> /dev/null

E_UNREADABLE=86

if [[ ! -r "test1" || ! -r "/Volumes/$1/test1" ]]
then
#echo "Both files to be compared must exist and be readable."
exit $E_UNREADABLE
fi

cmp test1 /Volumes/$1/test1  &> /dev/null  
OUT=$?

if [ ! $OUT -eq 0 ]; then
    exit $OUT
fi

#rm test1

exit 0
```

and the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Mac;
require Term::ANSIColor;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use threads;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);
use Getopt::Long;

sub result;
sub copyfunction($);


my $volumeName = " ";

GetOptions ('f=s' => \$volumeName);

sub main
{
    my $dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
    chdir $dirname;

    my $thread = threads->new( sub {   copyfunction($volumeName);});
    $thread->join();

    return 0;
}
exit(main());


sub copyfunction($)
{
    my $volumeName = shift;

    system("chmod +x ./copy.command");
    system( "./copy.command", $volumeName);
    if($? != 0) # 0 = files are identical
    {
        return(result(0, "volumeName" ,"failed to copy files"));
    }

    return(result(1, "volumeName"));
}


sub result($) #POF, functionName, reasonForFail
{
    my $POF = $_[0];
    my $functionName = $_[1];

    if($POF == 0)
    {
        my $reasonForFail = $_[2];
        print "$functionName || failed || $reasonForFail\n";
    }
    else{
        print "$functionName || passed ||\n";
    }

    return $POF;
}
```

Comment: well my problem is solved - i used absolute path to a folder i know exists with `mkflie` like so: `mkfile -n 1g $2/test1` ($2 is an absolute path).
although technically the real answer  isn't solved: where is the file if I don't use absolute path?